# trigonometry values in titanium not giving correct values

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

am calculating trigonometric values of cos,sin,and tan in titanium but its not giving correct values.
for exmaple

```
var val=Math.cos(90);
```

val should be zero but it gives me the -0.4480736161.
what's wrong in code line.
any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trig functions in JavaScript (as in many languages) operate on radians values, not degrees. The angular measurement in radians around a whole circle is 2π, so convert by multiplying the angle measurement in degrees by `Math.PI/180`.

You could make your own wrapper functions:

```
var MathDeg = {
  sin: function(d) { return Math.sin(d * Math.PI / 180); },
  cos: function(d) { return Math.cos(d * Math.PI / 180); }
};

var val = MathDeg.sin(90);
```

Comment: I assume that `6.123031769111886e-17` is almost `0` because doing `Math.cos(Math.PI/2)` returns that number. I guess it's a floating point number problem?

Comment: @LightStyle yes, exactly.  The trig functions themselves may involve some internal floating point, depending on how they're implemented. (I recall that the old, old Intel floating point chip only had "partial" trig functions, but that was 30 years ago :)

Comment: i've picked up radian value of 90 degree which is 1.570796327 then i used it in Math.cos(1.570796327); but results again different.it should be zero.

Comment: @Pointy +1, perfect! I would have defined `MathDeg` as a function, but it's almost the same thing if declared as an object(it is just for code style, I guess)

Comment: @LightStyle thanks - I wasn't really thinking about overall coding style, just the Math code :)

Comment: @TashenJazbi it may not be exactly zero, due to floating-point imprecision.  See the comment above from LightStyle.

Comment: @TashenJazbi read the comment, your result is `6.123031769111886e-17`? Surely it is. Now think of it as a floating 0 number... It has 17 zeros before the **6**... Is it really different to 0? ;)

Comment: Pointyand LightStyle,thank you both for the help.it helped me a lot.thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That value is correct but the input is taken in radians. pi radians = 180 degrees so if you don't know any other way to manipulate the functions to take an input of degrees you can simply change it to: cos(x in radians) = cos( (pi/180) *  x in degrees)